# Counting Prolog Database

Tags: prolog

How can I check if a query gives me a specific number of results.

So for example, I want to retrieve a car model of a car that has only been on three specific races.

The car predicate is : car(race#, name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% Car has been on N races
car_with_n_races(Car, N) :-
    length(Races, N),
    findall(Race, car(Race, Car), Races).
```

Use `setof` instead of `findall` if `car/2` may return duplicate results.

(You can swap the calls to `length` and `findall`, but I think this order may be more efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

car_with_n_races(Car, N) :-
    count(race(Race,Car),N).

count(P,Count) :-
    findall(1,P,L),
    length(L,Count).

Answer (score 0):

% sorry!

car_with_n_races(Car,N) :-
    count(car(Race,Car),N).

count(P,Count) :-
    findall(1,P,L),
    length(L,Count).